# Connect Multiple Networks Wirelessly

Tags: networking, router, wifi, switch, hub

1. I have a home network using a router to connect computers both wirelessly and with network cables.
2. I also have another separate network about 10m away from my home network that is networked via cables in a switch.

Is there a way for me to connect the two networks wirelessly?

i.e. make the switch connect to the router (Say for example, if I'm unable to connect the devices on the second network directly to the first network)

Answer (score 1):

This question is going to get marked as out of scope as it is not a professional environment; however, the technology you are looking for is called "Wireless bridge". It is two wireless devices that will connect to each other ad-hoc that also have a switch attached.

See **http://www.ezlan.net/bridging.html** for further explanation.

Comment: I really hate the stupid rules on stackexchange sites :(

Comment: This question belonged on stack exchange's Power User site. The rules make these sites as useful as they are.

Comment: What is the point? You already have your answer.